# Картинка поверх камеры (Андроид)

Tags: java, android

Есть экран с камерой, поверх камеры картинка (допустим, изначально во весь экран). При движении пальца по экрану (влево/вправо) ширина картинки меняется (сама картинка не сжимается).
Помогите, пожалуйста, придумать, как такое реализовать.

Пробовала менять размер камеры - искажается картинка (становится приплюснутой по бокам).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

xml-файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shareARButton"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/share_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/transparentARButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/horizontalPadding"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Прозрачность"
        android:textSize="@dimen/noveltyListTextSize"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="800dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".75" >

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Активити с камерой:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    private static String TAG = "Camera";
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    public String currentImage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_layout);

        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(getApplicationContext(), mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            currentImage = extras.getString("currentImage");
        }
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.arImageView)).setImageResource(R.id.image0);
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
        }
        catch (Exception e){ }
        return c;
    }
}
```

**Редактирование**

Использовала класс Bitmap [отсюда](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/catshop/bitmap.php)

Думаю, вопрос можно считать закрытым.

Comment: Ксения, покажите код, которым вы эти операции сейчас делаете. Тогда можно будет говорить о том, как его улучшать.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, добавила код. Меня интересует не "как двигать картинку", а "как вписать ее в заданные рамки, обрезав по ширине". Надеюсь, я понятно пишу.

Comment: вроде бы понятно. Я в андроиде не разбираюсь, вопрос плюсанул.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, я тот вопрос удалила, так как он был некорректный.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь любой из библиотек на GitHub, которые реализуют SlidingPanel. В вашем случае левый View по движению пальца должен быть шторкой, которые выезжает\заезжает слева.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

заменить `android:scaleType` на:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Растягивает изображение до контейнера и обрезает лишнее, сохраняя пропорции.

Comment: Он ставит центр картинки в центр области (в которую вписываем). А  мне надо, чтобы показывался только правый край картинки.